# How to match format of matching value? *Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

How to match format of matching value? *Google Sheets

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeZmS.png

[image]

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Hey there @familiacarballo, so let me understand more clearly - you want to make the text in `C1` cell match the conditional formatting of the `A1` cell based on the checkbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question, I think I have an answer for you.  See sample sheet here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QhED3qsoUiX0Km8R86Rg6kHdKdjwQW0uhHZeOd40Sy4/edit?usp=sharing

Note that this currently requires one formula for each of your due date columns, but these are easily dragged across, from D10, for as many columns as you need.  There may be a way to combine them as one, but I haven't figured that out yet.

This conditional formatting rule's formula is applied to include D10:D and across as many columns as you need - D10:I18 in this sample sheet.

```
=arrayformula(index($A$2:$C$18,match(D$9&D10,$A$2:$A$18&$B$2:$B$18,0),3))
```

which combines the date and the item name, finds them in the initial data, and sees whether the Paid checkbox is ticked.  If yes, it formats the text as "strikethrough".  For clarity, I've also formatted the cell to gray, but this is easily removed, in the formatting options for that conditional formatting rule.

**REFERENCE:**

[INDEX](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242?hl=en)

[ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en)

[Conditional Formatting rules](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform=Desktop)

Comment: Thank you so much.You're amazing! It worked!! I used =arrayformula(index($B$2:$C$10,match(D10,$B$2:$B$10,0),2)). Thank you again! God bless you (1 Corinthians 15 KJV)!

Comment: @familiacarballo  So glad you got it to do what you need.  Your question was not very clear, but I'm glad it worked out.

Comment: Where can I find documentation to explain this?

Comment: @aNewb See updated REFERENCES at the end of my answer.  The text in the answer explains the sequence of "actions" performed by the formula.  Click on cell D10, in the sample sheet I refer to, and select Format - Conditional formatting from the menu (or right click on D10, and select Conditional formatting) to see the formatting rules applied to that cell.